# How would I force a maximum angle between planes?

Tags: mesh

I'm creating a mesh made up of multiple intersecting curves for use in a Unity game. Due to the way the physics engine works with small rolling spheres, all transitions between faces need to be less than 5 degrees.

I have a decent workflow for straights (extrude, rotate five degrees or less, extrude, rotate, etc. then extrude everything sideways) and circles (same process, but rotate around the center at the end), but I'm having trouble figuring out a good way to accomplish this for multiple intersecting curves.

Is there a way to limit all angles in a mesh to five degrees or less? Maybe something involving converting bezier curves to a mesh or sculpting?

Here's a photo showing roughly what I'm trying to accomplish - a "crater" with a descending divot leading from the center to the outside.

[image: Multiple Intersecting Curves]

Thanks.